# NextJS getToken returns null on requests from server side components

Tags: next.js, axios, next.js13, next-auth

I was trying send get request to my backend but getToken returns null its working on client side component.

- Cookie Sharing:
  universal-cookie library was used.
  Client-server cookie sharing configuration was checked for a custom server.
- NextAuth.js Session Management:
  It was verified that sessions are stored in cookies.
  Session retrieval process was checked for a custom server-side provider.
- getToken Usage:
  The req object was passed as the first argument to getToken on the server-side.
  No arguments were passed to getToken on the client-side.

###### Http Service

```js
// add request interceptor http-service
httpService.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {

    const user = await getToken({ req: rqst});
    if (user) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${user?.accessToken}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  function (error: AxiosError) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

###### Next Auth

```js
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  secret: secret,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials as Credentials;

        return await loginUser(email, password);
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },

  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, trigger }) {
      if (user) {
        // Merge the additional properties with the access token
        token = {
          ...user,
          accessToken: user.accessToken,
        };
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      session.user = {
        ...token,
      };

      return session;
    },
  },
};
```

Where am I making mistakes ? Thnx for helps.

Comment: Where does that `rqst` in the http service's interceptor come from?

Comment: Sorry  İ forgot this part of code ! That was a method for create axios request. Rqst i a request parameter as a NextRequest type. İm calling this method in next API routes. And sending rqst from API route

Comment: you mean you are making this interceptor in the API route? and are you using the app router? or pages?

Comment: Yes İm using app router. And im making a request from page to API route and i have a method in user-service file this method taking a request parameter API iş calling this method with a NextRequest parameter. İm using createHttp service method in userService. Basicly im making a get request from backend like this. And sorry for my bad english :)